# With Windows 7 how to access a network with an other domain name?

Tags: windows-7, networking, openvpn, domain-name

I want to access my company's internal network from my home (on a PC running WIndows 7).
I received configuration details to use with OpenVPN and connected successfully (according to OpenVPN log).
I tried to copy-paste in explorer a link to a directory on the company network that I want to access. Then a window popped-up asking me my logging details and password. However under the "domain" info is the name of my home PC. I guess I have to change it to a domain name on my company's network ? How can I do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you type in your username, type `username@domain` or `domain\username`. Take your pick. If you want no domain, use `\\username`.

Comment: It worked, thak you for the answer.